# D3js chained animations as function of JSON

Tags: d3.js

I am learning D3js and trying to chain some animations together.

Basically I have three svg elements that I want to simultaneously transition.  There is a circle, a rectangle, and a text element.

For example, I am trying to make the circle transition from black to green, the rectangle transition from black to blue, and replace the text with a fade out, fade in effect.

I can do this one time, but I want a series of these animations to occur in sequence.

Here is the first fiddle of 1 transition working:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgcdanny/6nbRK/

Here is my attempt to sequence these using a for loop and JSON, but only the last transition happens:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgcdanny/U7StQ/

Perhaps this would be better as a series of enter(), update(), exit() commands?

Thanks for the help!

Fiddle 1 Code:
`

```
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', 500)
                        .attr('height', 500)

        var circle = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("circle")
                            .attr('cx', 10)
                            .attr('cy', 10)
                            .attr('r', 10)

        var rect = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("rect")
                            .attr('width', 20)
                            .attr('height', 20)
                            .attr('x', 30)
                            .attr('y', 30)

        var text = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("text")
                            .text("hello")
                            .attr("x",60)
                            .attr("y",60)
                            .attr('opacity',1)

        var tran = svg.transition().duration(2000)

        tran.select("rect").attr('fill', 'red')
        tran.select("circle").attr('fill', 'blue')
        tran.select("text").attr('opacity', 0)
        //new transition
        svg.transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .select("text")
            .attr('opacity', 1)
            .text("hello again!")
            .attr("x",60)
            .attr("y",60)

    </script>
</body>
```

`

Fiddle 2 Code:
'

```
        theData = [
                    {"words":"today", "rect_color": "red", "circle_color":"blue"},
                    {"words":"tomorrow", "rect_color": "green", "circle_color":"yellow"},           
                    {"words":"Day After That", "rect_color": "purple", "circle_color":"brown"}]         

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', 500)
                        .attr('height', 500)

        var circle = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("circle")
                            .attr('cx', 10)
                            .attr('cy', 10)
                            .attr('r', 10)

        var rect = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("rect")
                            .attr('width', 20)
                            .attr('height', 20)
                            .attr('x', 30)
                            .attr('y', 30)

        var text = d3.select("svg")
                        .append("text")
                            .text("hello")
                            .attr("x",60)
                            .attr("y",60)
                            .attr('opacity',1)

        var tranFunc = function(object){
            var tran = svg.transition().duration(2000)
            tran.select("rect").attr('fill', object.rect_color)
            tran.select("circle").attr('fill', object.circle_color)
            tran.select("text").attr('opacity', 0)
            var tran2 = tran
            tran2.transition().select("text")
                .attr('opacity', 1)
                .text(object.words)    
        }

        var allTran = function(list){
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                tranFunc(list[i])
            }
        }

    allTran(theData)
    </script>
```

'

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [chained transitions](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997).